# Data not transfered form $.ajax() to server side

Tags: jquery

Hi i want to post some string to server side on click of a button
and have code as follows

```
 $('#sendData').click(function () {
                  $.ajax({
                        url: '/home/SendData',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'string',
                        data: JSON.stringify(somedata),
                        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'                        
                    });
            });
```

And in the Controller i have method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public string SendData(string emaildat)
        {
              string data=emaildat;
        }
```

But emaildat is coming as null (data is not coming).

Is that ajax method is correct . Pls help me out

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `data` property of `.ajax()` requires either an object-map with key-value pairs or a string (which already must be a query-string).

So you can't just throw in a JSONized string there. Do it like:

```
data: {
    mydata: JSON.stringify(somedata)
},
```

And then access `.mydata` serverside (don't forget to parse it there).

Comment: If you set the key to 'emailDat' i'm pretty sure the modelbinder will pick it up and add it to the actionmethod's parameters too.

Comment: thank u . I have some doubt what data type i can specify for that Data (coming from Client side) Ex  public string SendData(string emaildat)
        {
              string data=emaildat;
        }
and  how can i parse it in the Server side.

Answer (score 0):

you could try serializing your form instead of sending it out as JSON.

```
data: $("#formid").serialize()
```